# How to fill an existing Acrobat fillable form from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, acrobat, mailmerge

I've been given several Adobe Acrobat `.pdf` fillable forms and asked to make them "auto populate" from an existing SQL Server database. MS Word would use "Mail Merge" to do this and you could search for any particular record that you want to populate the form with.

Can you do that with Acrobat `.pdf` files, either with or without a 3rd party plug-in or software? Preferably without, of course.

What I need is for staff to be able to open a `.pdf` form (maybe download it from an internal intranet site) to their PC or laptop, search for a specific record in the database and populate the form with the data from the database.

For example, find "Jane Smith" and all of her information populates the form. Then staff can print the completed form or whatever.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: This is NOT going to happen "from existing SQL Server Database". You will need some development environment that will support using a PDF in this manner.

Comment: There are a number of different ways to approach this. If your SQL database has an API that can be accessed via HTTP, you can do this entirely from within Acrobat but you will need to understand a lot about Acrobat JavaScript to do it... the core is the same but the object model is quite different from browser JavaScript. As @Smor said, research your options.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  I'm perfectly happy telling them that they get the forms in MS Word format or not at all.